# Can't get keyup event to fire on an icon

Tags: jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#FeedbackCloseIcon').click(function(e) {
    console.log('clicked icon');
  });

  $('#FeedbackCloseIcon').on('keyup', function (event) {
    console.log('button on icon');
    if(event.which === 13){
      console.log('enter on icon');
    }
  });
});
```

The issue I am having is the keyup event for the FeedbackCloseIcon not firing. The click event works fine.

```
<button class="dialog-close" aria-label="close" href="#" type="button">
   <span class="icon icon-close" id="FeedbackCloseIcon">x</span>
</button>
```

If I change the object for the keyup event to

```
<a class="dialog-cancel" id="cancel-feedback" href="javascript:void(0)">Cancel</a>
```

It works fine

```
$('#cancel-feedback').on('keyup', function (event) {
  console.log('button on icon');
  if(event.which === 13) {
    console.log('enter on icon');
  }
});
```

Comment: A `span` element isn't focusable, it cannot capture any key event. You could set `tabindex` attribute to make it focusable

Comment: Its unclear to me if what's working and what's not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Span keyup/keydown** Or any key **event not register in DOM**, you have to get it's parent mean Button keyup/keydown/keypress event.

```
    $(".dialog-close").keypress(function (e) {            
        console.log('enter on icon');
    });
```